# Why do I receive a Service Unavailable message after running the project GWT?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jetty, gwt-rpc, gwt-material-design

I am creating a GWT project from the GWT Material official website using maven. I am following the tutorial offered by the site: http://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#gettingstarted . Im getting this in the view page:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
Problem accessing /index.html. Reason:
Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://
```

I tried all the solution proposed here but I failed to view the project homepage.

There is no error in the eclipse console. but when inspecting the home page im getting this error:

Voice Instead ready.

```
content.js:29 Object
favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
    enter code here
```

after running the project 
in the window Developement Mode in the Jetty console next to Developement Mode
i have problem with Jetty. i don't know 
What is jetty and what it allows to do? Im getting this error :

```
`00:00:16,662  [WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@3772b95a{/,file:/C:/Users/Mm/eclipse-workspace/com-gwtmaterial-tutorial/target/com-gwtmaterial-tutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,STARTING}{C:\Users\Mm\eclipse-workspace\com-gwtmaterial-tutorial\target\com-gwtmaterial-tutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
<pre>java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 4178 but got 10926 bytes)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:384)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:196)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:207)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:140)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:118)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(JarInputStream.java:142)
    at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(JarInputStream.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar(AnnotationParser.java:915)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse(AnnotationParser.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call(AnnotationConfiguration.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run(AnnotationConfiguration.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)</pre>`
```

Comment: It looks like you have a corrupted JAR. I'd first try cleaning the project (`mvn clean`) in case it got corrupted during local copy; and if that doesn't fix it, then delete the Maven local repository (`.m2/repository` in your user home folder) to re-download dependencies. You might want to debug the devmode process to see which JAR exactly is causing the error. (btw, Jetty is the web server used to serve your webapp in devmode)

Comment: i did mvn clean but didn't work. then i deleted the repository  and do mvn install im getting  BUILD FAILURE

Comment: what to do now?

Comment: I am following the tutorial offered by the site: [link] http://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#gettingstarted

Comment: Can you give more details than just BUILD FAILURE? @ThomasBroyer is right, a repository directory clean should have fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by following the next step:

1- Close Eclipse.

2- Go to user directory and delete the .m2 directory.

3- Open Elipse.

4- Right click on the project -> Run as -> maven install